# google assistant demo crash S3 connection time out

Tags: raspberry-pi, google-assistant-sdk

When i try to launch the google assistant it crashes displaying the following error.

And when it reply it either say :

"There as been an error try in a few second" 
"There as been a glitch"

ON_MUTED_CHANGED:
      {'is_muted': False}
ON_START_FINISHED
    [19218:19229:ERROR:speech_processing_task.cc(646)] Detected communication error: Downstream closed prematurely.

```
ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_STARTED
[19218:19229:ERROR:speech_processing_task.cc(646)] Detected communication error: Downstream closed prematurely.
[19218:19229:ERROR:assistant_output_handler.cc(589)] Failed with a general speech recognition error
ON_ASSISTANT_ERROR:
  {'is_fatal': False}
ON_RESPONDING_STARTED:
  {'is_error_response': True}
ON_RESPONDING_FINISHED
ON_CONVERSATION_TURN_FINISHED:
  {'with_follow_on_turn': False}

[19218:19229:ERROR:speech_processing_task.cc(340)] S3 connection has timed out: No data from S3
[19218:19229:ERROR:speech_processing_task.cc(646)] Detected communication error: Downstream closed prematurely.
```

I am connected to the raspberry pi via ssh and can ping so i don't think it is a connection issue.

This my first post let me know if there is something i need to change or details i might have forget.

[upadate] i checked on myactivities and nothing appear in the logs but when I try with my smartphone it logs it properly
Also I updated my raspberry pi3 to the latest version and still no change in the error log

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
The thing was that the google assistant api wasn´t enabled.
do **ctrl+c** and run this command with **env**

```
python -m googlesamples.assistant.grpc.pushtotalk
```

When it says Press enter to send a new request, press enter and say something.
It will give you an error with a lot of command lines.
The last paragraph is important.
It´s here :-

`PERMISSION_DENIED, Google Assistant API has not been used in project integrigate before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/embeddedassistant.googleapis.com/overview?project=projectname then retry.
If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.)>`

copy and paste the link in your browser and click enable api.
once it is finished
run the command below
google-assistant-demo.
It should work now.

Yusonious